# Lambda function with if else clause with Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, lambda

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
A   B   C   D   SUM 
2   5   -4  12  15
```

I try and run:

```
df.apply((lambda x: x / x.sum() if x/x.sum() >= 0 else None), axis=1).fillna(0)
```

to get, if cell is same at total then calculate x/total:

```
A         B     C   D
2/15    5/15    0   12/15
```

I get:

```
'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can i improve the code.

Comment: what is `x/x.sum()` supposed to return?

Comment: Why not just check if a number is negative or not?  `x/x.sum()` will ever only be negative if `x < 0` or `x.sum() < 0`?  You wouldn't even need a `lambda` function.  You could replace all the negative values in the Dataframe with `None` and set rows whose sum is < 0 to `None` as well.

Comment: x/x.sum() is:  value in cell divided by sum of values in all cells of a row.

Comment: This isn't a problem with `if/else` or `lambda`, but of how a series of values should be treated as a boolean.

Comment: What does "if cell is same at total" mean?

Comment: Is this what you are tying to achieve: "How can I divide the positive values by the value of the SUM column, and assign 0 to the negative ones?"

Comment: FWIW it's a little strange to be incorporating the negative numbers as part of the row sum while zeroing out their fractional contributions.  Not unheard of, just rare.  Usually you either keep them in both or ignore them in both.

Comment: The end product penalizes congestion (positive) and  ignores de-congestion (negative).  Yes, in some instances both are considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). They are different methods: one works on a series and operates on each element; the other operates across the dataframe along an axis. In the latter case, along `axis=1` means each *row* is fed to the function sequentially.

Because these `apply` methods (both versions) are just thinly veiled loops, the dataframe will change after each columnwise `lambda` call. Therefore, you will need to work with a copy of the dataframe:

```
df2 = df.copy()

for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    df2[col] = df.iloc[:, :-1].apply(lambda x: x[col] / x.sum() if x[col]/x.sum() >= 0 \
                                     else None, axis=1).fillna(0)

print(df2)

          A         B  C    D  SUM
0  0.133333  0.333333  0  0.8   15
```

However, this is all very inefficient. We aren't utiling the underlying NumPy arrays. Instead, you can use vectorised operations:

```
res = df.iloc[:, :-1].div(df.iloc[:, :-1].sum(1), axis=0)
res.mask(res < 0, 0, inplace=True)

print(res)

          A         B    C    D
0  0.133333  0.333333  0.0  0.8
```